# How to access dictionary based on conditions?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to figure out how to access two different dictionaries, based on conditions being met, and applying to a data frame column, in python.

I have the following data frame:

```
Animal      Color 
------------------
   Dog       grey
   Dog       grey 
   Cat      brown
   Cat       grey
   Dog        red
   Dog      brown
```

I then have 2 separate dictionaries, one for "Dog", and one for "Cat":

```
dict_dog = {grey: 3, red: 4, brown: 2}
dict_cat = {grey: 2, red: 5, brown: 7}
```

I then want to append a new column to my data frame that produces a value based on the corresponding dictionary, as such:

```
Animal      Color     Value
----------------------------
   Dog       grey        3
   Dog       grey        3
   Cat      brown        7
   Cat       grey        2
   Dog        red        4
   Dog      brown        2
```

I am aware of how to use conditional statements, but I am unsure about how to use them with dictionaries. The conditions here are of course the "Animal" type and the "Color". How can I use these conditions to determine the "Value" based on my dictionaries?

Answer (score 0):

Don't really see the goal of selecting which one of the two dictionaries you'll take,

Why don't you just take both of them and store them in different variables? Then you could just select which one to use based on variable name?

Just asking, don't beg if I missed something that prevent this

Answer (score 0):

You wont need conditionals if you change your dict a bit:

```
dict = {'dog':{grey: 3, red: 4, brown: 2},'cat':{grey: 2, red: 5, brown: 7}}
```

this way you can access it by

```py
    for n,i in enumerate(animals.iloc):
      animals['value'][n] = dict[i['animal']][i['color']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with two loops

```
for color in dict_dog:
    df.loc[((df['Animal'] == 'dog') & (df['Color'] == color)), 'value'] = dict_dog[color]
for color in dict_cat:
    df.loc[((df['Animal'] == 'cat') & (df['Color'] == color)), 'value'] = dict_cat[color]
```

Or little more generic

```
dicts = {'dog': dict_dog, 'cat': dict_cat}
for animal, dictionary in dicts.items():
    for color in dictionary:
        df.loc[((df['Animal'] == animal) & (df['Color'] == color)), 'value'] = dict_dog[color]
```

Comment: This worked for me, thank you, though I did encounter an error I wanted to ask about. I tried the first code you wrote, the code with the two loops. I then tried it with another data set I have where the two dictionaries I am referencing are both integer: integer mapping. So in the example I have, replace the colors with integers. I then ran the code and got the error message: `TypeError: invalid type comparison`. Then I tried producing the new data frame in a new cell using `Jupyter Notebook` and it worked, and I cannot figure out why this is.

Comment: Actually, update, I went back to the full newly-produced data frame, and I see that under the `Value` column, the values corresponding to `Dog` reveal the correct value, but the values corresponding to `Cat` all read `NaN`. Do you know what potential errors might be causing this?

Comment: Ok I see this now, I see that I wrote "1" as `1.0` in my dictionary, and apparently Python did not like this. I then switched that value to `.86` as a random test, and your code worked fine. I am not sure why `1.0` would not be accepted here. I meant to say my dictionary is mapped as float: float.